# Работа с Windows Forms в Virtual Box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, виртуальная-машина

Для выполнения определенной задачи мне нужно использовать **Windows Forms**, но мой компьютер работает под **MacOS**. Смогу ли я использовать Windows Forms, если поставлю виртуалку и скачаю Visual Stidio, и если нет, то какой другой способ я могу использовать?

Comment: Виртуалки для этого и созданы )

Comment: @Kromster, окей, буду пробовать